# Chart.js Error: You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, chart.js

I'm currently attempting to use `Chart.js` within my react application but when I go to build my application I'm presented with this error

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/chart.js/dist/chart.esm.js
Module parse failed: D:\MyApp\node_modules\chart.js\dist\chart.esm.js Unexpected token (6613:12)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|         if (intermediateIndex1 !== startIndex && intermediateIndex1 !== lastIndex) {
|           decimated.push({
|             ...data[intermediateIndex1],
|             x: avgX,
|           });
 @ ./src/imports/Dashboard/Dashboard.js 21:12-31
 @ ./src/App.js
 @ ./src/index.js
 @ multi babel-polyfill ./src/index.js
```

I tried researching online to see if anyone else has had the same issue, but I had no luck.

Below is my Webpack config file:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: ['babel-polyfill', './src/index.js'],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/
    }, {
      test: /\.s?css$/,
      use: [
        'style-loader',
        'css-loader',
        'sass-loader'
      ]
    },{
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg|mp3)$/i,
        loaders: [
            'file-loader?hash=sha512&digest=hex&name=[hash].[ext]',
            'image-webpack-loader?bypassOnDebug&optimizationLevel=7&interlaced=false'
        ]
    }
    ]
  },
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    historyApiFallback: true
  }
};
```

And here is my bablerc file

```
{
    "presets": [
      "env",
      "react",
      "stage-0"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      "transform-class-properties"
    ]
  }
```

This is the list of my dependencies that are installed

```
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.0.0",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.580.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "7.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "6.24.1",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
    "chart.js": "^3.1.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.3",
    "css-loader": "0.28.4",
    "express": "latest",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.5",
    "google-maps-react": "^2.0.2",
    "image-webpack-loader": "^3.4.2",
    "immutability-helper": "^2.4.0",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "jsbarcode": "^3.11.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.1.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.14",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "node-schedule": "^1.3.2",
    "nodemailer": "^4.7.0",
    "normalize.css": "7.0.0",
    "npm": "^6.10.0",
    "papaparse": "^5.1.1",
    "promise-mysql": "^3.1.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
    "react": "^16.0.0",
    "react-csv": "^1.0.14",
    "react-dom": "^16.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "4.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.14",
    "sass-loader": "6.0.6",
    "socket.io": "^2.0.3",
    "style-loader": "0.18.2",
    "twilio": "^3.24.0",
    "validator": "8.0.0",
    "webpack": "3.1.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.5.1"
  },
```

I expected the error to tell me what loader I needed to install to use with `Chart.js` but it does not specify.  If anyone knows which loader I need to install and where I should put it in my files that would be awesome. TIA!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Chart.js version 3 is not compatible. Change it to ^2.9.4. The same problem as you and I have been solved.

Comment: Yep I actually figured this out a few days a go but thanks for the answer.  Maybe it will help others in the future.

Comment: what is it that Chart.js version 3 is not compatible with? I'm having this same error and the other two answers aren't working for me (I'm not using babel) and I'd really like to use chart.js version 3

Comment: @davidshere did you figure out which version to use? I am struggling with these errors

Comment: Is version 4 compatible?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error. I've just updated babel dependencies, some others, and the error is disappeared. But after that, you have to update some of the chart properties (for ex. `horizontalBar` to `bar` and configured with `indexAxis` option).

```
"@babel/core": "^7.15.8",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.8",
"babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a different setup so I'm not sure if the fix I used can apply here without additional tweaks, but since this is the best search engine match for this error, I'll share my results, maybe it'll help someone. There should be no need to stick with an older version of a library.

I'm using Webpack via Laravel Mix in Laravel 6 but my Mix package was very old, so the first thing I had to do was to update it to the current version (for Laravel 6 it's v5). After that I added the following .babelrc file:

```json
{
    "presets": [
        [
            "@babel/preset-env",
            {
                "debug": true,
                "modules": false,
                "forceAllTransforms": true,
                "useBuiltIns": "usage",
                "targets": "last 1 version, > 1%"
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

I also added the Babel polyfill package:

```
npm install -D @babel/polyfill
```

After that I can run `npm run dev` without any errors.

The file and the command come from this article: https://fostermade.co/blog/laravel-mix-and-es2015-javascript