# vue-chartjs 5 error: "You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file"

Tags: typescript, vuejs2, chart.js, web-frontend, vue-chartjs

I am running:

- "vue-chartjs": "^5.2.0",
- "chart.js": "^4.2.1",
- "vue": "2.7.14",

I believe these are the correct and compatiable package versions.

However when I try to run the project I get the error:

```
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
```

This question is related to but not the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75216646/vue-chartjs-you-may-need-an-appropriate-loader-to-handle-this-file-type-curren) as using chart.js 3.9.1 does not solve my problem. When using chart.js 3.9.1 I get the following full error:

```
 error  in ./node_modules/vue-chartjs/dist/index.js

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (198:37)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
```

Comment: As suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67081096/chart-js-error-you-may-need-an-appropriate-loader-to-handle-this-file-type/69855897#69855897 , have you tried `npm install -D @babel/polyfill` ?

Comment: I already have @babel/polyfill installed

Answer (score 0):

Vue 2 doesn't support the versions of vue-chartjs and chart.js.

I use the following versions

- "chart.js": "^3.8.0"
- "vue-chartjs": "^4.0.0"
- "vue": "^2.7.14"

You can find some examples of implementation over here:

https://vue-chartjs.org/examples/#vue-2-charts-vue-chartjs-v4

Comment: It clearly mentions in this migration guide that vue@2.7 is supported:

https://vue-chartjs.org/migration-guides/#esm

I have managed to compile the project with the same major versions that you mentoned though.

Comment: Documentation says: 'Vue.js < 2.7 is no longer supported. If you want to use vue-chartjs with Vue < 2.7 you have to lock your version to 4.x.", so it should be ok?

Comment: @EspressoCode, I am having the same issue as tomthedude, and I entirely agree with his reasoning, and his question.

"Vue.js < 2.7 is no longer supported. If you want to use vue-chartjs with Vue < 2.7 you have to lock your version to 4.x."

The plain reading is "Vue.js < 2.7" (e.g.., 2.6.x) is not supported (in chartjs v5). 
Further, that obviously that implies Vue.js ≥ 2.7 *is* supported (e.g., 2.7.15).

Comment: @tomthedude - Did you ever get this working?

Comment: @MatthewB ended up actually scrapping our entire vue2 project after we faced a few more compatibility issues along these lines, I think in this example the documentation here is just not accurate and in fact these versions are not compatible...

I would probably recommend moving fully over to vue3 if possible, but the whole migration process is very painful. Good luck

Comment: @Bob Schijf - according to the official repo owner, your answer is incorrect.  See [here](https://github.com/apertureless/vue-chartjs/discussions/993#discussioncomment-4624854) "**vue-chartjs v5 supports vue >= 2.7.0**".